# How to make a variable on an aspx page visible to multiple content sections on that page in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an aspx page that has multiple content sections in an ASP.NET MVC application. I need to calculate a value based on the page url (using a custom HtmlHelper) on the page and use that value in two of these content pages. How do I declare this value (or to be more correct the variable holding the value) so it is visible from both content sections.

Here is some detail:

```
    <asp:Content ID="indexTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
        <%
              var titleAndDescription = Helpers.TitleAndDescription.GetTitleAndDescription(Request.RawUrl); 
              Response.Write(titleAndDescription.Title);
          %>

    </asp:Content>

<asp:Content id="indexDescription" ContentPlaceHolderID="MetaTagsContent" runat="server">
    <meta name="Description" content=<%Response.Write(titleAndDescription.Description);%> />
</asp:Content>
```

So I want to calculate the variable titleAndDescription once and use it twice, once in each partial.

Comment: Your question suggests you aren't using MVC correctly.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Thanks! I added some code to the question to show what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could declare the variable outside those sections:

```
<script type="text/c#" runat="server">
    string foo = "bar";
</script>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    <%: foo %>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2><%: foo %></h2>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: @darin-dimitrov can we access these variables on code behind page?

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use that html helper value in your content sections. What's preventing you from just calling that HtmlHelper from within each content section?

If you must pass it, consider one of several techniques, ViewModel, TempData, etc but without seeing how you are using the content sections its hard to say.

Are you referring to a layout with multiple content sections?

Comment: Thanks!I am trying to be more efficient.  I want the value calculated once and then reused.  As opposed to recalculate it a second time.  This is an ASP.NET MVC2, not razor. So it is using ASPX pages and not layut pages. in the ASPX page there are multiple content sections.