# getting the Request.RawUrl into a string variable in <script type="text/c#">

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In an ASP.NET MVC aspx page I have the following script:

```
<script type="text/c#" runat="server">
    string rl = Request.RawUrl;
</script>
```

the `Request` is underlined in Visual Studio with the following error: 
An object reference is required for the non-static method, field, or property System.Web.UI.Page.Request.get

However this: `<%=Request.RawUrl%>` works fine.

Can you please tell me how I can get the RawUrl into the rl string variable in the script? Thanks!

This is a continuation of [How to make a variable on an aspx page visible to multiple content sections on that page in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737593/how-to-make-a-variable-on-an-aspx-page-visible-to-multiple-content-sections-on-t)

I basically am trying to declare an object on the page and referring to it in different parts of the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like that:

```
<%
    string rl = Request.RawUrl;
%>
```

or in your particular case:

```
<script type="text/C#" runat="server">
    string rl = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;
</script>
```

---

UPDATE:

According to your comment you want to use this variable from everywhere. In this case I would recommend you writing a custom helper that will be accessible in all views:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static string GetSomeValue(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        var context = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext.HttpContext;
        var value = context.Items["__some_key__"] as string;
        if (value != null)
        {
            // the value was found in the HTTP context => no need
            // to recalculate it
            return value;
        }

        value = ... do some expensive calculation to fetch the value
        // store the value in the HTTP context so that the next time
        // someone calls this helper from within the current HTTP context
        // doesn't need to perform the expensive operation
        context.Items["__some_key__"] = value;
        return value;
    }
}
```

and then when you need the value somewhere:

```
<%= Html.GetSomeValue() %>
```

Comment: but that rl variable will not be visible to the rest of the scripts on the page. this is a continuation of this question which you answered a little while back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737593/how-to-make-a-variable-on-an-aspx-page-visible-to-multiple-content-sections-on-t

Comment: @user277498, write a custom helper that will return this value. Don't use such global variables in an ASP.NET MVC view. It's just wrong. I will update my answer to illustrate an example.

Comment: thanks! I need to populate a bunch of meta tags with Facebook Open graph stuff and my own stuff. For each of them I am calculating the content. For example there is the regular description meta tag and the FB Description meta tag and the regular title tag and the FB title tag and so on. The calculation of all these takes the Raw URL as a parameter and I am trying not to run the same calculation multiple times. So I want to hold all these in one object and access them as needed on the page.

Comment: @user277498, you could *cache* the calculated value in the `HttpContext.Items` in your custom helper. This way you won't be doing the same calculation over and over again. The HttpContext.Items is available in the helper and its lifetime is the HTTP request. It's perfect for this scenario. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Thanks! And why is this the right way to do it as opposed to instantiating an object in a script tag at the top of the page and just referring to it throughout the page? That seems a lot more straightforward than this approach.

Comment: @user277498, because in ASP.NET MVC views are not supposed to contain whatever calculation logic. In a properly designed view you shouldn't have a single line of C# code. Views are there only to display values that are passed to them either under the form of a strongly typed view model or using some helper.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6865/discussion-between-user277498-and-darin-dimitrov)